# Creating a Bootstrap form - Cannot submit?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have made a bootstrap form that I have taken the code from bootsnipp.com

I have made the code function and appear as it should, but for whatever reason I cannot make it actually submit the form!

I have tried recalling scripts and ensured they all work, I have even made a new page called test.php with nothing but that code and it works wonderfully well.

Can I have some insight? Removed < head >< html > and < body > tags due to it causing issues

```
    <div class="logo">Teacher: Log in here</div>
```

I hope you can help

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jqBootstrapValidation.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/login.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />

<title>PsyRevise - A Better Way To Learn</title>

<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS - Uses Bootswatch Flatly Theme: http://bootswatch.com/flatly/ -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="css/freelancer.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom Fonts -->
<link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->





<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#page-top">PsyRevise</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="hidden">
                    <a href="#page-top"></a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-scroll">
                    <a href="student_login.php">Student Login</a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-scroll">
                    <a href="teacher_login.php">Teacher Login</a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-scroll">
                    <a href="#pricing">Pricing</a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-scroll">
                    <a href="#about">About Us</a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-scroll">
                    <a href="#contact">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

<!-- Header -->
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="intro-text">
                    <span class="name">PsyRevise - Teacher Login!</span>
                    <hr class="star-light">
                    <div class="text-center">
<div class="logo">Teacher: Log in here</div>
<div class="login-form-1">
    <form id="login-form" class="text-left" action="teacher_login_submit.php" method="post">
        <div class="login-form-main-message"></div>
        <div class="main-login-form">
            <div class="login-group">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="username" class="sr-only">Username</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username...">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password...">
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="login-button"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
        </div>
    </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>

<!-- Footer -->
<footer class="text-center">
    <div class="footer-above">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="footer-col col-md-4">
                    <h3>Location</h3>
                    <p>Gravesend<br>United Kingdom</p>
                </div>
                <div class="footer-col col-md-4">
                    <h3>Around the Web</h3>
                    <ul class="list-inline">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="btn-social btn-outline"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-facebook"></i></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="btn-social btn-outline"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-google-plus"></i></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="btn-social btn-outline"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-twitter"></i></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="btn-social btn-outline"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-linkedin"></i></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="btn-social btn-outline"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-dribbble"></i></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="footer-col col-md-4">
                    <h3>About PsyReviser</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed commodo nisl sed libero blandit mattis. Phasellus et nisl ac dui bibendum efficitur. Suspendisse mattis tempus porta. Curabitur quis velit non sem vulputate vulputate quis nec risus. Nam enim purus, molestie id tellus sed, bibendum tincidunt nib</a>.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-below">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    Copyright &copy; PsyRevise 2015
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>

<!-- Scroll to Top Button (Only visible on small and extra-small screen sizes) -->
<div class="scroll-top page-scroll visible-xs visible-sm">
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#page-top">
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
    </a>
</div>

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/classie.js"></script>
<script src="js/cbpAnimatedHeader.js"></script>

<!-- Contact Form JavaScript -->
<script src="js/jqBootstrapValidation.js"></script>
<script src="js/contact_me.js"></script>

<!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
<script src="js/freelancer.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add value in the input type of button as below and try.

```
<button type="submit" class="login-button" value="submit"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
```

Comment: I have changed this to no avail. Any other ideas?